# Exercise from textbook about norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, normed-spaces

The below diagram included a relevant page and the question 4 of the exercise which i am not sure how to do. Any hint or solution are welcome

Attempts:

- a) I have done it
- b) i have tried to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x^i|^p$ is a norm. If it is a norm, it seems that i can apply (2.4) and immediately follows $K$ has the 4 properties. But it seems it isn't a norm so is there any other way to prove the property?
- c) I don't know what does "norm associated with K" mean.[image]

[image]

Comment: I can hardly read...

Comment: @julien is there any way to enlarge it?

Comment: Other than enlarging your scan and posting again? I don't know.

Comment: The "norm associated with $K$" is the norm defined by $(2.5)$ in Theorem 2.13.

Comment: @DavidMitra O i see, but i don't quite get, isn't it already defined the norm as $1\over \max{}$?

Comment: Yes. Take that definition and then show, with a bit of computatuion, that  it actually gives $\Vert x\Vert=\Bigl(\sum_{k=1}^n |x_i|^p\Bigr)^{1/p}$.